# Creating alert using prometheus everytime there is an error

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I am new to prometheus and alerting system.
I have developed a microservice and added metrics code to get the total number of increments whenever there is an error.
Now I am trying to create an alert so that whenever there is an increment in the error, it should flag out and send a mail.
but I am unable to form a proper query for this scenario. I have used something like error_total > 0 to send an alert but it will work everytime since the count will be > 0 unless we reset it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [increase function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase). The following expression trigger en error whenever there was an error in the previous 15min:

```
expr: increase(my_error_metric[15m]) > 0
annotations:
  summary: "Hey! There were {{ $value }} errors in the last 15 minutes"
```

Errors are common in microservices and alerting on each of them is generally unmanageable. A more common strategy is to alert only when the [error rate](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#irate) exceeds a given threshold (by example 5%):

```
expr: irate(my_error_metric[2m]) / irate(number_of_call[2m]) * 100 > 5
```

Alerting on increase may also mean you can miss some errors because the alert is triggered on the error but another error occurs during investigation. There won't be a second alert, it will be included in the first one.

Comment: Hi @Michael Doubez , thank you for your response. 
The expression increase(my_error_metric[15m]) > 0 does not returns any response for the first error, but once the second error comes the expression returns a value such as 1.66 etc. What can be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Do you publish the metric when there is no error ? (with value 0) That's the only thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Will this trigger a separate alerts for all consecutive alerts within 15min?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Alert expressions detect a state; a signal is sent by prometheus (to alert manager) whenever the state changes and at regular interval. If there is no error increase during 15 minutes, the alert will be resolved; if there is an increase, the alert is in "firing" state. If you are talking about notification, it is handled at alert manager level.