# Creating alert using prometheus when there is some error happened

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I just following page [Creating alert using prometheus everytime there is an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60667510/creating-alert-using-prometheus-everytime-there-is-an-error) to config a alert. The increase function works well.

```
expr: increase(my_error_metric[15m]) > 0
```

But it will send an another alert after 15m indicated that the error is recovered. But actually, the error is not recovered.

**My question is that whether there is some way to avoid the 'error is recovered' alert?**

Comment: Alertmanager can be configured to not send "resolved" at all or for specific routes, or you can increase the interval in the `expr` so that it will fire for a long time. Though I suppose you wouldn't like either of these options in production. What is the use case? What are you trying to achieve? Is it just to remind people that the error is not yet fixed?

Comment: @anemyte my use case is build a way to alert support team that some error happened in our service. There are some existing alert rule (i.e. CPU usage high, memory usage high). The support team will work to resolve these alert. When the issue is resolved. Then a "resolved" message will be sent out indicating the issue is solved. 
But for this error, I do not want to send a "resolved" message just due to the time range is passed.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to avoid sending "resolved" for some alerts, first thing you need is an additional receiver:

```yaml
# alertmanager.yml
receivers:
- name: do_not_send_resolved
  email_configs:
  - to: me@example.com
    send_resolved: false
  # this "send_resolved: false" can be configured for every kind of receiver
  # e.g. telegram below:
  telegram_configs:
  - send_resolved: false
    bot_token: ...
- name: default
  # merge with your current receiver configuration
```

Then you need a route that will lead to this receiver. I can't say how exactly you can integrate this into your environment, but consider this example:

- if an alert has a label `receiver=do_not_send_resolved`, then use this receiver;
- otherwise use the `default` receiver (assuming you already have it)

```yaml
# alertmanager.yml
# root route (where all alerts go)
route:
  # child routes
  routes:
  - matchers:
    - receiver="do_not_send_resolved"
    receiver: do_not_send_resolved
  - matchers:
    - alertname=".+"
    receiver: default
```

Finally, label your alert configuration accordingly:

```yaml
# your file with prometheus alert rules
- alert: myAlert
  expr: up != 1
  labels:
    receiver: do_not_send_resolved
    severity: blah
    blame: putin
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am afraid in my environment. I cannot touch the alertmanager.